# Django Form with ForeignKey field NOT NULL constraint failed Error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Each model is chain-linked to the previous model. I make one form to fill in, since all the models are linked. When I try to link a model address to a project, an error appears

> NOT NULL constraint failed: crm_project.address_id
> /crm/views.py, line 39, in add_project
> form_project.save()

**Models**

```
class City(models.Model):
    obl = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=REGIONS, default="24", verbose_name="Регион")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name="Город")
    population = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Address(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Город")
    street = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Улица")
    numb = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name="Номер дома")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.street}, {self.numb}"

class Project(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Сотрудник")
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Адрес")
    # another fields

class ProjectDetail(models.Model):
    project = models.OneToOneField(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Проект")
    # another fields
```

Forms

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ["city", "street", "numb"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        city = kwargs.pop("city", "")
        super(AddressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["city"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())


class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["file", "sq", "rent_tax"]

class ProjectDetailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectDetail
        exclude = ['project', 'comment', 'resume', 'complite', 'created_at']
```

**Views**

```
def add_project(request):
    form_address = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    form_project = ProjectForm(request.POST or None)
    form_detail = ProjectDetailForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form_address.is_valid() and form_project.is_valid() and form_detail.is_valid():
            address = form_address.save(commit=False)
            form_project.manager = request.user
            form_project.address = address
            project = form_project.save(commit=False)
            form_detail.project = project

            form_address.save()
            form_project.save()
            form_detail.save()

    
    context = {'form_address':form_address, 'form_project':form_project, 'form_detail':form_detail,}

    return render(request, 'crm/project_form.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `ProjectForm` you specified these fields only `fields = ["file", "sq", "rent_tax"]`
but as per Your Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Сотрудник")
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Адрес")
```

There two fields are `null=False`Means every instance of `Project` must have these `Values` which you're not providing in the `ProjectForm`

to handle this error you can do 2 things as per your need.

1. replace this form with this:

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__"
```

or another option which is not how you should use foreign keys.

2. change your class with this and makemigrations and migrate again:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Сотрудник")
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Адрес")
```

Comment: I didn't specify the other fields in the sample code because there are so many of them. They exist. My form works. The address is saved, but the value is not set in address field model Project

Comment: check `form_project.address` you're getting value before saving?